# How to implement a user defined class in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, user-controls

Hi I am trying to implement a user defined class in a WPF Window?

The strange thing is that I already did this but this time it just does not work and I cannot find my error ...

This is the class:

```
Namespace Controls

    Public Class WorkingPopup
        Inherits Primitives.Popup

        Public ReadOnly WorkingLabelProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WorkingLabel", GetType(Label), GetType(WorkingPopup))
        Public ReadOnly WorkingProgressBarProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("WorkingProgressBar", GetType(ProgressBar), GetType(WorkingPopup))

        Private Property WorkingLabel As Label
            Get
                Return GetValue(WorkingLabelProperty)
            End Get
            Set(value As Label)
                SetValue(WorkingLabelProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property
        Private Property WorkingProgressBar As ProgressBar
            Get
                Return GetValue(WorkingProgressBarProperty)
            End Get
            Set(value As ProgressBar)
                SetValue(WorkingProgressBarProperty, value)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()

            Placement = Primitives.PlacementMode.Center
            StaysOpen = True
            PopupAnimation = Primitives.PopupAnimation.Fade

            WorkingLabel = New Label With {.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible, .Content = "Working", .ContentStringFormat = "{0} ..."}
            WorkingProgressBar = New ProgressBar With {.Height = 20, .Width = 200, .Margin = New Thickness(5)}

            Child = New Border

            With DirectCast(Child, Border)
                .BorderBrush = SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush
                .Background = SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrush
                .BorderThickness = New Thickness(1)

                .Child = New StackPanel

                With DirectCast(.Child, StackPanel)
                    .Children.Add(WorkingLabel)
                    .Children.Add(WorkingProgressBar)
                End With
            End With
        End Sub

        'Some more irrelevant code
    End Class

End Namespace
```

This is a bit of my XAML:

```
    <RibbonWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Controls"
              Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Children>
            <ctrl:WorkingPopup/>

        </Grid.Children>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Maybe it is because its monday morning ... but I don't get it ...

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell that I can compile this project but the designer cannot create the design view anymore and at the line `<ctrl:WorkingPopup/>` I get the error **The Name "WorkingPopup" does not exist in Namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication3.Controls"**

Comment: Is WorkingPopup in the same assembly of MainWindow?

Comment: Yes, both are part of WpfApplication3

Comment: Where do you define RibbonWindow?

Comment: I add the reference **Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon**.

Answer (score 0):

Change the namespace of WorkingPopup from Controls to WpfApplication3

Comment: In order to put **WorkingPopup* into the **WpfApplication3 Namespace** I had to remove the **Namespace** because otherwise I just got the Namespace `WpfApplication3.WpfApplication3` which a suspect not to be your intention. After that the error still remained.